# How to read floats and integers in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that takes a string (as a file), and in that file it contains numbers (in integers and floating points) on separate lines.I then want to print the numbers in the file that are greater than zero. I am pretty new to python, so I am having a little trouble getting the output to work.
so far I have:

```
def getPositive(filename):
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    content = (infile.read())
    infile.close()

    for number in content:
        if number <= 0:
            print (content.remove(number))
```

and I keep getting the error

```
>>> getPositive('nums1.txt')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    getPositive('nums1.txt')
  File "/Users/XXXX/Desktop/test.py", line 8, in getPositive
    if number <= 0:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() <= int()
```

Also, in my file i have:

```
59
-3.2
12.99
-1
45.3
20
```

and I want it to only print:

```
59
12.99
45.3
20
```

Could someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong and what I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`float()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) to turn the string from the file into a number:

```
for line in content:
    number = float(line)
    if number > 0:
        print(number)
```

There is no need to read the whole file in memory; process it line by line instead:

```
def getPositive(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            number = float(line)
            if number > 0:
                print(line.rstrip())
```

The `with` statement makes sure the file object is closed automatically.

Output:

```
>>> getPositive('/tmp/test.txt')
59
12.99
45.3
20
```

Comment: so when I added 
    infile.close()
was that wrong, or does using the with statement just makes it neater?

Comment: You do not need to use `infile.close()` at all when using `with`. See http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example

Comment: maybe use `print line,` instead of the float that preserves intness and newlines

Comment: @sleeplessnerd: this is Python 3; I opted to strip the newline instead.

Comment: An oversight on my part. But you got the concept :)

Comment: @Martjin Pieters Thanks for that, it helped me understand the with statement, I haven't learned that yet.